# ionic ios FCMPlugin.onNotification function not working

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-fcm

I am using cordova-plugin-fcm. The FCMPlugin.onNotification function is not getting called on IOS when the app is in background. The same function works properly on Android. How to get the function working on IOS?